# Having Difficulty with Landscape Layouts

Tags: android, orientation

Although I have created a `layout-land` folder, my app is still displaying the portrait layout when orientation is changed to landscape.

My problem is in my initial `Activity`, the other Activities seem to be working well in landscape mode.

My manifest is as follows:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"> 

    <activity
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


     <activity 
         android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
     <activity
         android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
     <activity 
         android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
    <activity 
         android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>      
         <activity 
         android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remove the attribute `android:configChanges` from your manifest for the activities that you want to respond to the layout files in your `layout-land` folder.

When you specify `android:configChanges="orientation"` (along with the keyboard events), you're telling Android that you the developer are going to handle the orientation changes, and the system should **not** destroy and recreate the Activity.

This behavior is contrary to the default, which is to destroy an Activity, and recreate it with proper resources according to the current orientation.

Comment: thank you, that works.

but this time when orientation changes, activities are being created again